# How to validate boolean with XML using Expression

Tags: struts2

I have boolean field in action

testMeAction.class

```
private boolean testMe;
// with setter and getter.
```

testMeAction-validation.xml

```xml
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN" "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
<validators>
  <validator type="expression" short-circuit="true">
    <param name="expression"><![CDATA[(testMe == false)]]></param>
    <message key="user.message" />
  </validator>
</validators>
```

I would like to validate and display message when `testMe = false;`
But for some reason, it always displaying message, what ever value of `testMe` is.

Please can someone advice, where I am going wrong.

Comment: `<![CDATA[testMe]]>` and you can use `fieldexpression` instead of `expression`.